# Sorting Keys and values of an arrary , key being the Month

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with keys as Month and values as total expense of that month.

```
[May: 629, April: 300, March: 50]
```

I want to order this array on the basis of the key i.e. month.
My desired result:

```
[ March: 50,  April: 300, May: 629]
```

I have tried to sort the key by doing this:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var sorted_keys = Object.keys(arr).sort(function(a,b){
  return months.indexOf(a)
           - months.indexOf(b);
});
```

How can i sort the whole array?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Invalid syntax. You got an array of what?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Array of keys only from sorted_keys .
["March", "April", "May"]

Comment: Arrays in all normality have integer indexes (while possible to assign other properties, it's highly discouraged). `[May: 629, April: 300, March: 50]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: If your array just looks like `["March", "April", "May"]`, then change your sort from `Object.keys(arr).sort(...` to `arr.sort(...` and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var op3MembrosDisp = [];

var w = { id: 2, name: 'karen' };
op3MembrosDisp.push(w);

var w = { id: 1, name: 'Joseph' };
op3MembrosDisp.push(w);

op3MembrosDisp.sort(
            function (a, b) {
                var aId = a.name;
                var bId = b.name;
                return ((aId < bId) ? -1 : ((aId > bId) ? 1 : 0));
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input is an array of String with a format like "month: expense", the idea is to extract the month from that entry, and sort that array based on month. Now to sort the array, we use the month map where each month is ranked.

```
var monthsHash = {
    "January": 1,
    "February": 2,
    "March": 3,
    "April": 4,
    "May": 5,
    "June": 6,
    "July": 7,
    "August": 8,
    "September": 9,
    "October": 10,
    "November": 11,
    "December": 12
};

var input = ["May: 629", "April: 300", "March: 50"]

input.sort(function (a, b) {
    var a_month = a.split(":")[0],
        b_month = b.split(":")[0],
        a_month_rank = monthsHash[a_month],
        b_month_rank = monthsHash[b_month];

    return a_month_rank - b_month_rank;
});

console.log(input);
```